# Oracle SQL in string matches and table joins

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, plsql

I need some guidance on how to approach this problem.

Consider the following 3 tables:
[image]

I inherited this dataset in Oracle.  I need to find a way to merge these 3 tables into a single table.  Why?  Compliance and fraud checks.  We're being audited, I have no choice but to comply.

The tables are millions of records.  69million.  7 million, 4 million.  If I try to join and search by using contains, or instr or like, I'd be creating Cartesian joins (I think) and it will be quite slow.

How do I approach this?  The data is formatted with the square brackets as in the picture.  I have considered pulling these tables into pandas and using python to get the answer.

The resulting table would look like this:
[image]

Comment: What is the resulting table supposed to look like? What's the format of `Concat_identifier_plate`?

Comment: The format of concat_identifier_plate can either be the identifier number of a person or a team, or 2 people, with a fish.  It's really convoluted in some places.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is going to be slow anyway, there're multiple meals and teams for a person which might lead to an unpredictable increase in the number of combinations. By the way, why is the "George" record duplicated in the sample result?

Comment: Because both George and Jenny appear in the same teams string.  
This is honestly a messy issue.  I'm thinking of deconstructing the data first maybe, by table, and stitching again.  There might just not be an easy answer.

Comment: This might be a good idea. I'd also start with splitting concatenated strings into numeric ids. This should be relatively trivial (e.g. `select to_number(regexp_substr(concat_identifier_partner, '[0-9]+', 1, 1)) as first_person_id
from teams)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your first step would be to get the meals and teams tables in a usable format. Using these weird concatenation columns is never going to be easy or fast.

Doing something simple like *[this](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-in-oracle/)* to split the ids onto different rows:

```
select trim(column_value) partner_id,
       team
  from teams,
       xmltable(('"' || replace(teams.concat_identifier_partner, ']',']","') || '"'))
```

Gives an output like this:

```
+------------+------+
| PARTNER_ID | TEAM |
+------------+------+
| [012345]   | Blue |
| [012346]   | Blue |
| [012347]   | Red  |
+------------+------+
```

Then you could use these as inline views in your query or create a new temporary table for each of these. The temporary table would allow you to index them on the new ID column.

After your data is in the easier format, the joins become easy.

```
select people.identifier,
       people.name,
       formatted_teams.team,
       formatted_meals.meal
from people
join (select trim(column_value) partner_id,
              team
       from teams,
       xmltable(('"' || replace(teams.concat_identifier_partner, ']',']","') || '"')) ) formatted_teams
  on people.identifier = formatted_teams.partner_id
left join (select trim(column_value) plate_id,
            meal
       from meals,
       xmltable(('"' || replace(meals.concat_identifier_plate, ']',']","') || '"')) ) formatted_meals
  on people.identifier = formatted_meals.plate_id
order by people.identifier
```

Output:

```
+------------+--------+------+--------+
| IDENTIFIER |  NAME  | TEAM |  MEAL  |
+------------+--------+------+--------+
| [012345]   | George | Blue | Salmon |
| [012346]   | Jenny  | Blue |        |
| [012347]   | Alex   | Red  | Pike   |
| [012347]   | Alex   | Red  | Cod    |
+------------+--------+------+--------+
```